# It's possible know when the HttpURLConnection was established?

Tags: java, connection, httpurlconnection

I'm using the `HttpURLConnection` to open connections to web pages. I call the `connect()` method to open the connection.

I not found an `isConnected()` method.

I need to know when the connection was established with the server. I need this because I tryinf to found a fast way to open multiple connections. One object open connections and another do some processing with the connections that established the communication with the server.

I want to let the processor always busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would need that information.

You should not care since once you call `connect()` you can start retrieving the response e.g.

```
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();//Get HTTP status code
```

Assuming of course you have send all your request to the output stream.

The `HttpURLConnection` under the hood knows if it is already connected to the server and the implementation reuses the connection (transparent to you).

Now, having said that to answer your question, I think that the only way to know if the `HttpURLConnection`'s state is connected to the server, is to call `openConnection()` a **second** time in the **same** `HttpURLConnection` object.

If it is already connected it will throw a relevant exception complaining that it **is already connected** something like: `IllegalStateException("Already connected");`.

At that point you know that the `HttpURLConnection` is connected

Comment: This information is needed because these objects (`URLConnection` instances) have different behaviour depending on the state (pre- or post-`connect()`). Code handling `URLConnection` instances needs to determine their state if they are to handle them correctly - _without_ necessitating a state change - and shouldn't be assumed to be in the same context as that responsible for making the connection.  For example, if you wrote a function to dump all gett'able values from a `URLConnection` instance - how would you handle the header fields?

Answer (score 0):

```
httpURLConnection con = new httpURLConnection(some URL object);

con.getHeaderField(httpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED );
```

Comment: header information can be messed with, and I avoid relying on the header for anything.  however, this should head you in the right direction.